# Numerically solve overdetermined linear matrix system

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I have known real matrices $A\in \mathbb{R}^{\ell \times n}$ and $B\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, where$$\ell \gg n\gg m.$$I want to find numerically a real matrix $X\in \mathbb{R}^{\ell \times m}$ such that$$A=XB.$$As exact solution is probably not possible (the system is probably overdetermined or inconsistent), an optimization method will be necessary. For my purposes a "good" $X$ will probably be "small" (in terms of sum of squared absolute value of elements), and of course $A-XB$ will need to be "small" too.

How to find the "best" $X$?

(As I expect $A$ to be quite large, taking about 4GB of RAM in single precision floating point, methods that don't require lots of extra space are to be preferred.)

Comment: This really depends on what you mean by small. You should edit your question and explain what you mean and why solving your system in the least squares sense is not suitable for your application.

Comment: @CarlChristian I don't know what "solving in the least squares sense" involves, so it's quite possible that it'd be suitable!  By "small $X$" I mean that if say $[a,-a]$ is a (part of) a solution for arbitrarily chosen $a$, then choose $a = 0$ instead of some huge value.  But that probably is unlikely to occur for an overdetermined system, so perhaps "small $X$" can be ignored and just need to have "small $A-XB$".

Comment: Solving the system in the least squares sense will minimize the the Frobenious norm of the residual. Many introductionary textbooks on linear algebra will cover the case of a single right hand side. The key words is the QR factorization. Don't use the normal equations for anything practical.

Comment: @CarlChristian Comparing https://towardsdatascience.com/qr-matrix-factorization-15bae43a6b2 (for example) I have my formula transposed, so I should solve $B^T X^T = A^T$ via $QR = B^T$ and $X^T = R^{-1} Q^T A^T$?

Comment: That is correct. Don't rely on the source you have for any programing. Find a source that does modified Gram-Schmidt or reorthogonalization.